# Is the set of continuity of a function $f: X \to Y$ a $G_\delta$ set when $Y$ is first countable?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a metric space, for a function $f : X \to Y$ we can define
$$
\text{osc}_f(x) = \inf_{x \in U \in \tau_X} \text{diam}(f[U]).
$$
If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then, by definition, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have that $x \in \text{int}f ^{-1}[B_\epsilon(f(x))]$, so $\text{osc}_f (x) < \epsilon \Rightarrow \text{osc}_f (x) = 0$. Conversely, if $\text{osc}_f(x) = 0$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an open $U$ containing $x$ s.t. $\text{diam}f[U] < \epsilon$. Since $f(x) \in f[U]$, for all $y \in U$ we have $\text{d}(f(y), f(x)) < \epsilon$ so $f[U] \subset B_\epsilon(f(x))$. Because $B_\epsilon(f(x))$ form a neighborhood base for $f(x)$, we see that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Finally, $\text{osc}_f (x) < \lambda$ iff there exists an open $U$ containing $x$ s.t. $\text{diam} f[U] < \lambda$, so in particular we have that for any $y \in U$, $\text{osc}_f (y) < \lambda$, and $\{\text{osc}_f < \lambda\}$ is open. Since
\begin{align*}
 \{x : f \text{ is continuous at } x\} &= \{ x: \text{osc}_f(x) = 0\}
\\
&= \bigcap_n \{x : \text{osc}_f(x) < n^{-1} \},
\end{align*}
we have that the set of continuity of $f$ is a $G_\delta$. My question now is how much can this be generalized. My first thought was that we could conceivably replace $Y$ with a first countable space which would play the same role as the $\{x : \text{osc}_f (x) < n^{-1}\}$, but I am having problems finding an analog of the diameter.

Is it true that the set of continuity of a function with a first countable co-domain is a $G_\delta$ or is there a counter-example?

Comment: For a metric space $Y,$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, let $D(n)=\{x\in X: osc_f(x)\ge  1/n\}.$ I reviewed the proof that $D(n)$ is closed. It uses the fact that if $x\in D(n)$ and if $f(x)\in V$ where $V$ is $any$ open $Y$-ball of diameter $1/n,$  then any nbhd of $x$ contains some $x'$ with $f(x')\not\in V.$ The  the rest of the proof fails if $Y$ is not metric. I am not able to generalize this either. There $might$ be a counter-example.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I have to say I do not know enough topology to conjure up an example, but I would not be surprised if the claim were false.